# Can I use @string resources for layout attribute, like layout_height with dip?

Tags: android, xml

I want to use param for the same alignment in Android layout XML. Like some TextView use same layout_height. (I know it can use styles, but I find Android styles is not support multi-parents.) So I want use a param for this.

It is my solution:
layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@string/text_height"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

and in string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="test_height">40dip</string>
</resources>
```

I find it works in Eclipse ADT preview. But when I run it on real devices, it crashed and show :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #23: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

I want to know what could do for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should use dimensions resources
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is just to declare some dimension, just use a `<dimen>` resource instead of a `<string>`:

in values/values.xml declare:

```
<dimen name="test_height">48dp</dimen>
```

and use it in your layout file:

```
    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/test_height"/>
```